# wrap element around span text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `span` which is filled dynamically. The markup then is

```
<span class="child">
  John Doe <br>
  johndoe@gmail.com<br>  
  0123456789<br>
</span>
```

what I intend to do is wrap another `span` around the text before the first `<br>`. It should then be like

```
<span class="child">
  <span class="firstrow">John Doe</span><br>
  johndoe@gmail.com<br>  
  0123456789<br>
</span>
```

How can I detect all text before the first `<br>` and wrap another span with class around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can use the `contents()`, `first()`, and `wrap()` methods:

```
$('.child').contents().first().wrap('<span class="firstrow"></span>');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/contents/
- http://api.jquery.com/first/
- http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

A caveat I see with this approach is, I'm using a class selector, not an ID selector, so this code could muck with multiple DOM elements in a page (but that could be what you want also, so it depends on your context).

Comment: this one works. just made a change to create a jQuery `span` element to use on the wrap. here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yPP7F/26/
good job mrk

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method:

```
// Find what we want to transform
var span = $("span.child");

// The first node in the span's contents would be 
// the text up to the first non-text node, i.e. up to the first <br/>
var firstNode = span.contents().first();

// Wrap it with a span with the class we want
firstNode.wrap("<span.firstrow></span>");
```

Also see the example in jQuery's documentation, which does something quite similar.